# how to start tightvnc on a boot using init.d?

Tags: startup, vnc

I have created the file in the init.d dir:

```
! /bin/sh
case "$1" in
  start)
    sh /home/orangepi/.vnc/vnc_start.sh
    ;;
  *)
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

and then run the `update-rc.d vnc defaults`

But nothing happens after the reboot, and my script does not run.

The actual `/home/orangepi/.vnc/vnc_start.sh` script is just `vncserver -geometry 1440x900 -depth 16`.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The first line should be  `#!/bin/sh` but maybe that is just a copy/paste error? Also, your script does not have the [LSB dependency information comment block](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts) which is necessary on any distribution that uses `systemd` as its init system, and also required by modern versions of `update-rc.d`. Did you not get an error message when you ran `update-rc.d vnc defaults`?

Comment: It looks like the `tightvncserver` package does not include any example scripts to start it at boot: the `/usr/share/doc/tightvncserver/README.inetd` even describes how to set it up with a classic `inetd` daemon, which is a bit old-school. These days, that kind of setup would be done using a `*.socket` unit of `systemd`, or at least with `xinetd`. Apparently `tigervnc-standalone-server` package would have a modern, `systemd`-style setup (see `systemctl cat tigervncserver@.service` for instructions in comments); could you use that instead, or do you have a reason to use `tightvnc` specifically?

Comment: @telcoM there was no specific reasons to use tightvncserver, it was just one of the top lightweight vncservers that i found online. Also I quite liked the simplicity of it, as I am the new linux user, recently bought an Orange pi(raspberry alternative). I tried installing tigervnc, but I am unable to connect, the port doesnt seem to open. So i thought of sticking with tightvnc. But i did find out what was the reason for the vnc to fail:
`vncserver: The HOME environment variable is not set.`
So is there a way i can automatically start it as one of the users?

Comment: I also added the info block, and i guess in order for the vnc process start successfully, i need to put proper `# Required-Start:` processes, but i don't know which one to put.

Comment: Update: I added `su - zhekch -c vncserver...` and it now works.